# A javascript upload progress display in HTML5

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am very new to js and html programming. I am using following code to make a progress-bar which displays file upload progress. But it is not working on tryit editor

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
.progress-wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
.progress-wrapper .progress {
    background-color:green;
    width:0%;
    padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
</style>
<script>
function postFile() {
    var formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append('file1', $('#file1')[0].files[0]);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
        var file1Size = $('#file1')[0].files[0].size;

        if (e.loaded <= file1Size) {
            var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / file1Size * 100);
            $('#progress-bar-file1').width(percent + '%').html(percent + '%');
        } 

        if(e.loaded == e.total){
            $('#progress-bar-file1').width(100 + '%').html(100 + '%');
        }
    });   

    request.open('post', '/echo/html/');
    request.timeout = 45000;
    request.send(formdata);
}
</script>
</head>
<form id="form1">
    <input id="file1" type="file" />
    <div class="progress-wrapper">
        <div id="progress-bar-file1" class="progress"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="postFile()">Upload File</button>
</form>
</html>
```

I have tried on my local system too,it is not working here too. What I am doing wrong? Please tell me how can I improve the code. I want to display a progress-bar which shows upload percentage of file using ajax calls.

Comment: "is not working" is not a clear problem statement. Do you see errors in the console? It's behaving weirdly (and, if yes, how)?

Comment: The division does not shows at all for progressbar.

Comment: You should be using the `<progress>` element for this: https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/

Comment: Nicholas Shanks I have to support internet explorer too, will that do it?

Comment: @SamJoeseph it will degrade to a SPAN in browsers that don't support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add reference of [`JQuery`](https://jquery.com/) in your `head` before writing any `JavaScript`. Please see correct version below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
.progress-wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
.progress-wrapper .progress {
    background-color:green;
    width:0%;
    padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function postFile() {
    var formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append('file1', $('#file1')[0].files[0]);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
        var file1Size = $('#file1')[0].files[0].size;

        if (e.loaded <= file1Size) {
            var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / file1Size * 100);
            $('#progress-bar-file1').width(percent + '%').html(percent + '%');
        } 

        if(e.loaded == e.total){
            $('#progress-bar-file1').width(100 + '%').html(100 + '%');
        }
    });   

    request.open('post', '/echo/html/');
    request.timeout = 45000;
    request.send(formdata);
}
</script>
</head>
<form id="form1">
    <input id="file1" type="file" />
    <div class="progress-wrapper">
        <div id="progress-bar-file1" class="progress"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="postFile()">Upload File</button>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: It is still not working, please tell me if you need anymore details

Comment: Where are you testing it?

Comment: you can test it here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FM69GVNGDTP7

Comment: please tell me if you have solution for internet explorer too? It hangs to certain amount of percentage and does not work there after.

Comment: Sorry, but I am on mac not on windows. :(

Comment: what if upload fails ?

Answer (score 8):

A version without JQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
.progress-wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
.progress-wrapper .progress {
    background-color:green;
    width:0%;
    padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
</style>
<script>
function postFile() {
    var formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append('file1', document.getElementById('file1').files[0]);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
        var file1Size = document.getElementById('file1').files[0].size;
        console.log(file1Size);

        if (e.loaded <= file1Size) {
            var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / file1Size * 100);
            document.getElementById('progress-bar-file1').style.width = percent + '%';
            document.getElementById('progress-bar-file1').innerHTML = percent + '%';
        } 

        if(e.loaded == e.total){
            document.getElementById('progress-bar-file1').style.width = '100%';
            document.getElementById('progress-bar-file1').innerHTML = '100%';
        }
    });   

    request.open('post', '/echo/html/');
    request.timeout = 45000;
    request.send(formdata);
}
</script>
</head>
<form id="form1">
    <input id="file1" type="file" />
    <div class="progress-wrapper">
        <div id="progress-bar-file1" class="progress"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="postFile()">Upload File</button>
</form>
</html>
```